# Android - ListView doesn't receive OnItemClick for textview with clickable links

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a ListView that contains a TextView in each row besides a number of other views. The TextView renders html content which may contain links.

The below code appears in the list adapter.
            m_textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            m_textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(myhtmlcontent));

This causes the listview to no longer receive on click events though. I decided to put the list onclick code on the view being returned by the adapter instead. This doesnt quite work as desired. Now I can launch another activity when I click anywhere in the row except the textview. I want users to be able to click on the non-links part of the textview and launch another activity.

If I move the onclick to the textview instead of its parent view, it works but now a click on the link fires two events - one for the click on the link and another for the textview (which is not desired).

I have noticed that google+ and peep on android work in the manner I want. I'm not sure how that can be achieved.

Answer (score 23):

This is actually a [BUG](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414#c27). To resolve this you can add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` you your `ListView's` rows layout xml. For e.g

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblStatusMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Source : [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414#c27) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697908/android-how-can-i-add-html-links-inside-a-listview)

Good Luck :)

Comment: It may be too late.. BUT I was having the same issue and found this unanswered post. :)

Comment: I am unable to do this with a long click listener on my item parent with a textview autolink

Answer (score 1):

Focusable views inside a ListView item will disable the ability to select ListView items. Applying `android:focusable="false"` to the TextView will allow OnItemClick to work again. You may also need to apply `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to make the trackball ignore the links because clicking the trackball over a focusable element in a ListView can both click the link and the ListView item.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach on the list view an setOnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of these answers worked for me. Eventually, I managed to fix the problem by removing the attribute  `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`.

Answer (score 0):

TextView that only responds to touch events of links. Based on
                       https://stackoverflow.com/a/7327332/1768722

```
        public class AutoLinkTextView extends TextView {

            public AutoLinkTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);
                init();
            }

            public AutoLinkTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
                init();
            }

            public AutoLinkTextView(Context context) {
                super(context);
                init();
            }

            private void init() {
                this.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
            }

            /**
             * @Linkify applies to a movementMethod to the textView @LinkMovementMethod.
             *          That movement method thought it implements a scrolling
             *          vertically method it overrides any other scrolling method the
             *          parent has.
             * 
             *          Although touchEvent can be dispached to the parent, the specific
             *          parent ScrollView needed the whole sequence ACTION_DOWN ,
             *          ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP to perform (sweep detection). So the
             *          solution to this problem is after applying @Linkify we need to
             *          remove the textView's scrolling method and handle the @LinkMovementMethod
             *          link detection action in onTouchEvent of the textView.
             */
            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                final TextView widget = (TextView) this;
                final Object text = widget.getText();
                if (text instanceof Spannable) {
                    final Spannable buffer = (Spannable) text;
                    final int action = event.getAction();

                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                            || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        int x = (int) event.getX();
                        int y = (int) event.getY();

                        x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
                        y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

                        x += widget.getScrollX();
                        y += widget.getScrollY();

                        final Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
                        final int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
                        final int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

                        final ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off,
                                ClickableSpan.class);

                        if (link.length != 0) {
                            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                                link[0].onClick(widget);
                            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                Selection.setSelection(buffer,
                                        buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]),
                                        buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
                super.setText(text, type);
                this.setMovementMethod(null);
            }
        }
```